# How to clear User console?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not sure if you guys are familiar with Readytoprogram, but in that version of java, i could write a code called: c.clear; //which would clear all text above. I am now learning eclipse, and wanted to know if I can do this in eclipse aswell.

the c in the c.clear is the console, so I tried something like system.clear or system.out.clear, but either even work.

```
//Ready to Program: 
c.println("Hello World");
Thread.sleep (100);
c.clear;
//console would be cleared

//eclipse
System.out.println("Hello World");
System.out.clear();
//how to clear?
```

Just says that clear is a method or something

Answer (score 0):

I guess the clear is just a method in Readytoprogram and Java. Most programming language support a method like clear with their own way.